# Drupal Download Count module - How to count the number of downloads

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using the Download Count module in Drupal 6.  I have files that I've uploaded via file field in CCK.  I simply want to count the number of times users have downloaded them.

Using views seems to just output ALL data for all files.  Is there a way for me to simply put "387 Downloads", for example, next to my file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Count has default views like
individual_file_downloads and  file_downloads and my_download_count.

check this page "your site address"/file_downloads. there is a download count column.

Comment: Thanks, but how I do pull out just the download count value for a particular file so I can theme it?  I'd like to have it in a node next to the downloadable file that just says, "42 Downloads" for example.

Comment: if you like to display download count in node go to content type. select manage field  and go to display field .you can choose "generic files with download count" option in teaser and full node.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've already selected the "generic files with download count".  When I use Themer Info I do not see any download count variable associated with that node.  Is it a variable I can access, or do I need to use views?  I'm not sure how to get access to that number and associate it with the file in the node.

Comment: in garland if you follow my instruction you can see download count. variable is $node->field_"field_name_here"[0]['view']

Comment: Thank you, I see it.  It says, "[Name of File].zip -- Downloaded 3 times".  However, is it possible for me to theme this?  I don't want the full file name of the .zip (I'd rather have just "Download now" and I don't want the "Downloaded 3 times" to appear right next to it.

Comment: you can theme your content type with  http://drupal.org/project/contemplate after module installation you can see a tab in your content type and edit view of content type